# knockout image src binding issue

Tags: knockout.js

I have save store image name in database and image file in local folder 
I have used to bind the image

```
<img width="16px" height="16px" data-bind="attr:{src: PhotoName}"  />
```

in html it's show

```
<img src="http://sitename.com/Controller/action/imagename.extension"/>
```

but I need

```
<img src="http://sitename.com/imagefolder/imagename.extension"/>
```

any idea how can i fix this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `PhotoName` contain? Only `imagename.extension`?

Comment: Why do you think that it's a knockout issue? What do you store in `PhotoName`?

Comment: Onliy photo name and extension in database and image is in a folder

Comment: I am new diving to the knockoutjs and i've got face this situation to.. I just found a simple solution for this. `<img class="lazy" data-bind="attr: { src: '../imagefolder/' + PhotoName, alt: Name }" />`

The solution is just **../** use before path and then you get result what you need. Even though this question was asked 3 year ago, i still wanted to share it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to with kncokout.js. If your `PhotoName` only contains the `imagename.extension` you need to build your image path by hand in order to display the images correctly.

So you need to create the correct path either in the binding directly:

```
<img data-bind="attr:{ src: '/imagefolder/' + PhotoName }" />
```

Note if your `PhotoName` is a `ko.observable` then you need to write `src: '/imagefolder/' + PhotoName()`.

Or move this logic inside your viewmodel e.g. creating a computed property which does the link building or when you create your viewmodel assign the correct url to `PhotoName` etc.

Comment: 1st I Have added this : <img data-bind="attr:{ src: '/imagefolder/' + PhotoName }" /> but its not working. but now its working because of "()"

Comment: How about input type ="file" ?

Comment: does the note applies only to the cases, when the values are concatinated? in my case `<img data-bind="attr:{ src: resultImage }" />` works fine even if `resultImage` is observable.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz yes, the note only applies to the cases when you have some complex expression inside the binding like a string concatenation. If you only directly bind to an observable property then you don't need to write the `()`